# Error: Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#

To write the numbers in my motherhood language (**Persian**), I worked with the sting which its value is `1393` (The numbers are in Persian).

```
return Convert.ToInt32(Year);
```

But the following error appears:

> Input string was not in correct format

I have tried both `String` and `string`

Comment: Showing us `1393` is not helping much, that will convert.

Comment: There's an overload for `Convert.ToInt32()` that lets you provide a specified culture as your `IFormatProvider`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No, Do u have a reference link?

Comment: @Salman: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7e175yd(v=vs.110).aspx It works in a similar way to Henk Holterman's answer.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir");
int x = Int32.Parse(inuptString, info);   // same as Convert.ToInt32()
```